# Check whether the limit exists or not. If it exists, prove!

Tags: calculus, limits

Given
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)} \dfrac{2x^3 - y^3}{x^2 + y^2}$$
Check whether the limit exists or not. If it exists, then prove it.

[image: The example of proof]

I have included the example in the textbook (it's Indonesian), but I am sure you understand by only seeing the math expressions.
If you ask me whether I understand it or not, I will answer yes!
But for the problem above, I don't have idea where to start. 
What I know we need to use the triangle inequality rules here.
Please help me. (prove by using $\delta$ and $\epsilon$)

Comment: The hint is in the second line of your book: you have $|x|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now $|2x^3-y^3|\leq 2|x|^3+|y|^3$.

Comment: You should pay attention to @Kelenner. It leads to a simple proof.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use polar coordinates $\rho\to0$

$$ \dfrac{2x^3 - y^3}{x^2 + y^2}=\dfrac{2\rho^3\cos^3 \theta - \rho^3 \sin^3 \theta}{\rho^2}=2\rho\cos^3 \theta - \rho \sin^3 \theta=\rho(2\cos^3 \theta -  \sin^3 \theta)\to0$$

Comment: How do you prove it by using delta and epsilon?